# Sql server is not opening

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, c#-2.0

[image]

when i try to open my sql server this message pops up...

see the blue link, when it click "Here" it takes me to the site and the site says We're sorry, this download is no longer available. what should i do.....

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Not opening or Not Installing?

Comment: Can you share the url of the link ?

Comment: You've labelled your image SQL Server 2010, but no such product exists/existed. SQL Server 2008 R2 was succeeded by SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Why not upgrade you visual studio 2010 to something newer (2017 is already available...)

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 - whow. Your computer is in a museum?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691

Comment: thats the link, it was working fine two days ago and suddenly it happen.

Comment: try this one: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21835

Comment: This doesn't "open SQL Server", it opens SQL Server Management Studio.  Even if you are on some archaic version of SQL Server there's nothing to stop you installing the latest (SSMS 2017) version of Management Studio to allow you to develop SQL, view your databases, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all,the problem has been solved, the problem was i had both 2010 and 2013 VS installed on my pc and i was using only 2013, 2010 needed some upgrades so it was blocking the SSMS studio. All i have to do, was to uninstall 2010 VS.